# Unable to disable SSRS 2008 page breaks

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, page-break

I've always hated working with SSRS and I'm currently pulling my hair out over page breaks.

My report has a table with products which are grouped by a purchase. I want all purchases' product tables to appear on a single page, instead of one page for each unique grouping value.

Whenever I Google how to disable paging everyone points to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/6c240863-216b-4e6a-9c67-197d98b0f18c/) which I have followed - both interative height and width are at 0.

Starting at my table (wtf is a 'tablix'?) I have checked the PageBreak property of every container and all are set to 'None'.

The **ONLY** way I have so far managed to disable paging is to edit the report's XML and replace every instance of `<BreakLocation>Between</BreakLocation>` with `<BreakLocation>None</BreakLocation>`. According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reportingservices.rdlobjectmodel.breaklocations.aspx) `None` is a valid value, but after this change Business Intelligence Developer Studio can no longer display the report, complaining "Deserialization failed: Requested value 'None' was not found". **Slow clap for BIDS.

My three specific questions are:

1. Why can't I see the BreakLocation property anywhere in the report designer?
2. Why is BreakLocation being set to 'Between' when everywhere possible I have set PageBreak to None?
3. Is there any other way I can achieve what I desire that doesn't require editing the XML before and after using the designer?

I am using Business Intelligence Developer Studio 2008 and rendering reports in HTML.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in your XML by finding your `<Page>` tag and adding

```
<InteractiveHeight>0in</InteractiveHeight>
```

in the beginning (or replacing the existing one).

(A tablix is a combination of a table and a matrix, it's what 2008 does with your reports. Easier to see if you use Report Builder 2.0)

Comment: Thanks for the input but as you will see from my question the interactive dimensions are already at 0 with no effect

Comment: Did you add it in the XML as a part of the Page tag, or somewhere in BIDS in some property pane?

Answer (score 0):

You say you checked the page break location on every "container", but Tablix groups can also have their own page breaks.  You'll need to check those too and make sure they are set to None.

I can't speak for why BIDS isn't allowing you to specify None as a BreakLocation.  None certainly is a valid value as far as RDL is concerned.

With InteractiveHeight set to 0 and certainty that there are no BreakLocation tags in your report set to anything other than None, there really shouldn't be any pagination.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Ath first I used the xml to find the tablix or tablix group which contained the page break. Later I found out that it could be solved by removing the PageBreak section entirely from the xml.